# Guide for developing J2ME applications

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I am new to J2ME and what I have now is Netbeans 6.7.1 IDE. Is there any basic guide for developing Mobile applications in Netbeans 6.7.1? Please provide me the links.

Answer (score 3):

I think this book best source for J2ME with Netbeans:

[Kicking Butt with MIDP and MSA: Creating Great Mobile Applications (The Java Series)](http://gigapedia.com/items/116580/kicking-butt-with-midp-and-msa--creating-great-mobile-applications--the-java-series-)
[image]

Book Description:

The release of MIDP 2.0 and the introduction of the new Mobile Service Architecture (MSA) are generating momentum for the Java ME platform. As more and more Java-enabled mobile devices become available and more service providers become open to third-party development, the demand for customized applications will grow dramatically. Now, there's a practical, realistic guide to building MIDP 2.0/MSA applications that are robust, responsive, maintainable, and fun.

Long-time Java ME author Jonathan Knudsen offers real solutions for the complex challenges of coding efficiency, application design, and usability in constrained mobile environments. Experienced Java developers will master MIDP 2.0 and MSA programming through clear, carefully designed examples. Downloadable code is available for both NetBeans Mobility Pack and the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit. Kicking Butt with MIDP and MSA's wide-ranging content covers:

- Pushing MIDP's limits, and exploiting MSA's full power
- Using MIDlets, Forms, commands, core classes, and invocation
- Building effective mobile user interfaces
- Designing graphics with the Canvas, the Game API, SVG, and 3D
- Providing storage and resources: record stores, FileConnection, and PDA PIM
- Internationalizing mobile applications
- Networking via WMA, Bluetooth, Web services, and SIP
- Parsing XML documents
- Implementing audio and advanced multimedia
- Securing mobile applications with SATSA and the Payment API
- Building advanced location-based applications
- Designing applications for multiple devices
- Creating end-to-end mobile application architectures

Comment: This is probably the best book about J2ME ("Java ME"), and I use it in the J2ME programming course that I teach. But note that it is about J2ME in general (the APIs and so on), and doesn't say much about development environments. Netbeans is mentioned on half a page, and that's about it.

Comment: I tried to find a recent book on Micro Edition too, will try this one first. Amazon Reviews seems to be good enough :)

Answer (score 3):

**Netbeans.org** itself has great tutorials for mobile development in Netbeans. And that is what you need:

http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/mobility.html

For examples this is a very good Quick Start for Netbeans J2ME development:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Tell what platform you are developing on so that the tools available for you can be given.

Also, you most definitely want an emulator so that can test your applications directly on your computer (Saves time).

Honestly, can't give much more advice than to know java well and to use google + stackoverflow.  Those are what I did and ended up developing a commercial app in j2me just fine.